# Arduino +squidbee GSM shield + ethernet shield

Tags: arduino, ethernet, gsm

I am triying to make a webserver of the ethernet shield to send SMS messages via the squidbee GSM shield
Apparently i can't connect both the GSM shield and Ethernet Shield to the Arduino...
Is this possible? Is there any sort of pin incompatilibity i have to reroute ?
edit:
GSM shield: [link](http://www.libelium.com/squidbee/index.php?title=New_GPRS_module_for_Arduino_%28Hilo_-_Sagem%29)
ArduinoEthernetShield: [link](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield)

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shieldlist.org/ and see if you can find your shields in the list. 1) The shield list shows the pins used by each shield, so you can see if the shields are using the same pins. 2) If you are still stuck, you can point the rest of us to the shields you are using to better help you out.

Comment: i don't know what pins are used by the libelium shield yet :(

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use both of them, the GSM modlule uses some sort or serial connected to the Tx and Rx pins per the tutorials, I have seen. the ether net shield uses SPI for its comms on pins 11,12,13.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on the Tutorials section of Cooking-Hacks in order to know the pins used by GPRS Module. [Tutorial GPRS](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/index.php/documentation/tutorials/arduino-gprs-quadband)

Answer (score 0):

And there is an example of how to send the incoming data through GPRS in this tutorial.[Tutorial sending SMS with SquidBee](http://www.sensor-networks.org/index.php?page=0823923911)

Answer (score 0):

However, if you have some doubts when you try to do that, you can post in the forum too.[Forum](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/index.php/forum-1.html)

I hope this information helps you with your project.

Comment: i posted in the forum but still... no answer from anyone... i thought libelium was better as customer support than this.